# Cannot read property 'firstName' of null at render

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a lockers table with some lockers assigned to students and others are unassigned (Null studentId) When I try to return Student.FirstName I get an error. I see the correct data when I log in the console.

> Cannot read property 'firstName' of null
>       at render

*Note:* I am attempting to return first Name in a render function because I am trying to concatenate the first and last Name.

**The code:**

```
var table = $('#LockerTable').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/lockers',
    dataSrc: '',
    'data': null
  },
  columns: [
    {data: 'lockerNumber'},
    {data: 'location'},
    {
      'data': 'student.firstName',
      'defaultContent': '',
      'render': function (d, t, r) {
        if (r.student.firstName !== null) {
          console.log(r.student.firstName + r.student.lastName);
          return r.student.firstName + ' ' + r.student.lastName;
        }
        return '';
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: well check if `student` is null before trying to use it

Comment: @PatrickEvans Simple I previously attempted to check if firstName was null not student itself.

Comment: Could you show us the response of `/api/lockers`?

Comment: Checking if `r.student.firstName` is null does you no good if **`r.student`** is null, as Patrick pointed out.  Logically `r` could potentially be null, `r.student` could potentially be null, and `r.student.firstName` could potentially be null.

Comment: @Taplar I thought that even if the  individual student properties were null,  the student itself is not null, apparently I was wrong.

Comment: You are doing object access.  If any one of the objects in the chain of access is null, you will get an error if you try to access a property off of it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized, with the help of Tapler and Patrick evans I have to check The student property  itself if it is null.

```js
var table = $("#LockerTable").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "/api/lockers",
    dataSrc: "",
    "data": null
  },
  columns:  [
    {data: "lockerNumber"},
    {data: "location"},  
    {
      data: "student.firstName",                           
      defaultContent: "",
      render: function (d, t, r) {
        if (r.student !== null) {
          console.log(r.student.firstName + r.student.lastName);

          return r.student.firstName + " " +  r.student.lastName;
        }            
        return "";
      }                                                                                  
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: I think `columns` is supposed to be an array.  Otherwise, this code is invalid.